# Why is there no pdffrag package?

Tags: pdftex, psfrag, postscript

The [`psfrag` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) has been around for more than a decade<sup>*</sup> and is easy to use:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{psfrag}% http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag
...
\psfrag{<tag>}{<LaTeX text>}% <tag> -> <LaTeX text>
\includegraphics{image}
```

The drawback is the required `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` route of compilation for output to be produced in PDF format. Why is there no such easy/straight-forward counterpart for this under `pdflatex`? That is, by replacing all `psfrag` references to `pdffrag` in the above code extract.

<sup>*</sup> [`psfrag` version 3.04](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf) on CTAN is dated 11 April 1998.

Comment: Do you know [pdfrack](http://www.onera.fr/staff/marc-boyer/pdfrack.php).

Comment: PDF is binary which makes replacing material difficult. You would need to disassemble and reassemble the PDF file in order to insert material which can't be done using `pdftex` I guess.

Comment: @Marco: Yes, but it is still a workaround. From the [package README](http://mirror.ctan.org/support/pdfrack/README): `The pdfrack.sh script uses a lot of other scripts and software.
cut, dvips, epstopdf, grep, head, latex, ps2ps, ps2epsi, sort,
tail, and, first of all, a bourne shell... Sorry for Win* users. They should install solutions like Cygwin, or try a Linux distribution.`

Comment: @Werner: Every solution which is listed in the documentation is a workaround. I think Martins comment is the solution.

Comment: @Marco: If this is true, "difficult...I guess" should probably be "virtually impossible". I thought, with [technical foundations in Postscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Technical_foundations) and an [open file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#File_structure), access to elements contained within a PDF would have been developed by now.

Comment: @Werner: Sure it is possible to change elements in a PDF, but there seems to be no way or tool which can do it from a inside of `pdftex`. It's simply much more complicated then in the case of PS.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Right. It could be possible in LuaTeX, though.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: How? LuaTeX can't modify external PDF files any better than `pdftex`, or can it? And calling some external tools can also be done using shell escapes.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: With the `epdf` library in the latest versions of LuaTeX you might be able to manipulate the included pdf to create similar results as psfrag.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Any documentation on this?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: [`pdfrack`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfrack) has a new home on CTAN.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, a bit of background. With traditional (La)TeX, including an EPS file is relatively straight-forward at the TeX end. The approach taken by LaTeX is to read the EPS (a text file) to find the bounding box, then leave enough space for this to appear in the output. A link is included in the DVI file using a `\special`, and the TeX engine is done. Actually rendering the EPS file is then left to the driver.

What `psfrag` does is include an additional header to be read as part of the EPS file loading, along with the search-and-replace material to actually make the change. So the work is still not done by TeX.

Switching to pdf(La)TeX, directly generating a PDF means writing a PDF file. That requires the appropriate engine support, but more importantly has to include PDF graphics in the correct way. Unlike the EPS format, it's not possible to 'slip in' a header to do replacement within any included PDF files. Thus it would require engine support (a primitive) to do any replacement in a PDF. (There's also the fact that PDF files are not purely text, unlike EPS files, so a simple search-and-replace operation is not really possible.)

Comment: quoth the [uktug faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=labelfig): since `psfrag` works in terms of (encapsulated) PostScript files, it needs extra work for use with `PDFLaTeX`. The `pst-pdf` package can support such usage. In fact, the `pst-pdf` support package `auto-pst-pdf` offers a configuration setting precisely for use with `psfrag`...which sounds similar to `pdfrack`, except with more self-confident authors(!)

Comment: @wasteofspace: [`pdfrack`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfrack) has a new home on CTAN.