# Why aren't my psfrag substitutions occurring?

Tags: psfrag

I can't get simple `psfrag` substations go happen, and wonder if I'm missing an option or preference somewhere that will make them work.

I'm using LyX to build by document, but I have the same problem in nearly every tool I try. The only way I've been able to get substitutions to happen is by choosing `Typeset > TeX and DVI` in TeXShop using a MWE. But that's not were I build my actual document, and I don't think I can (and probably don't want to) make the equivalent change in LyX, where I actually work.

Is there some way I can modify the code below to so that substitutions will occur, using pdflatex (if that's even relevant)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\psfragfig*{graphA}{
    \psfrag{X}{$\epsilon$}
} 

\psfragfig{graphA}{
    \psfrag{X}{$\pi$}
} 

\psfragfig!{graphA}{
    \psfrag{X}{Q}
} 

\psfrag{X}{Help}
\includegraphics{graphA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The odd thing is, I *swear* that this once worked (just a few days ago) but now it's not.

Comment: You can only use [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) using `latex`. See [Why is there no `pdffrag` package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/5764) I haven't tried things with [`pstool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstool) though.

Comment: @Werner: So I can't use it with my build process, where I have use `pdflatex`?

Comment: Could you be having the `\psfragfig` and `\pstool` commands mixed up?

Comment: @Werner: I get the same outcome if I substitute `\pstool` for `\psfragfig` in the MWE.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I have a backup of an old latex version and there it works.
So I think it could introduced by a latex update (I use Miktex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get correct typeset psfrag (and pstricks) stuff when compiling tex-->pdf directly, you should use the package `auto-pst-pdf`, which in a first run creates a file `\jobname-pics.pdf`, which collects all eps files converted to pdf embedding pstricks stuff.

You only need `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` in your preamble.
If this `-pics.pdf` is created an you don't change your pics any more, you may set the option [off] to the call of `\usepackage[off]{auto-pst-pdf}` to get faster compilation.

To give a working exmaple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}

Some text

{
\psfrag{P1}{$P_1$}\psfrag{a}{\alpha}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{TestEps}
}

{
\psfrag{P1}{$Q=P_1$}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{TestEps}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to get that to work I need to enable "shell escape". Is that safe?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius This is often needed, even when translating with lualatex. I think it's harmless when you compile your own code. But when you compile foreign code then it might be that something could be executed you didn't want.

Comment: When I try this (in LyX) using my full document (not just the MWE) it takes forever (10 minutes, even if I import no EPSs) and then fails. If I turn `auto-pst-pdf` off (with the `off` package option), things are fine. Are there package interactions I should avoid? Everything (else) worked fine before adding `austo-pst-pdf`.

Comment: Clarification: "fails" means no graphic is produced in the final document or, sometimes, the rendering fails completely (perhaps because of a timeout).

Comment: It seems, that `\psfragfig` doesn't work properly. It works, when used as in my added example

Comment: Part of my problem seems to be [related to `microtype`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59150/7844).

Comment: As per Will Robertson, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11844/15717 `pstool` is more apt for psfrag applications. `auto-pst-pdf` for `pstricks`. 'pstool' is much faster way for using `psfrag` with `pdflatex`

Answer (score 5):

As you know by now, `psfrag` requires `latex->dvips` chain and will not work with `pdflatex`.

A possible (ugly) workaround is to create a minimal document which only includes that figure and uses `psfrag` to do the replacement of the labels, and compile that document with `latex->dvips->pstopdf` (or perhaps `latex->dvipdfm`), to obtain a `pdf` file containing only that figure. You can use also `preview` package to create a pdf with a page size that fits exactly the size of the included graphic.

Once you have created the pdf figure this way, you can import it in your "main" file via `\includegraphics`, and use `pdflatex` to process that file.