# PSfrag isn't working to add LaTeX symbols to eps figures

Tags: eps, psfrag

I have converted a jgraph file to eps, and am trying to replace text in the eps figure with LaTeX symbols. I have followed the instructions listed in [this  question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58988/why-arent-my-psfrag-substitutions-occurring/59056#59056) but the solution suggested does not seem to work for me.

Here is my short snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample PSFrag}
\maketitle

Hi there.

{
  \psfrag{rmax}{$r_{max}$}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{lusearch9}
}

\end{document}
```

The string occurs in the eps file: `\(rmax = 0%\))` but still no substitution happens in the final pdf file produced. I am using `pdflatex --shell-escape sample.tex`.

Any suggestions, especially using the pdflatex mechanism, would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf`?

Comment: The original figure is produced, without the substitutions. So, rmax is not replaces with r_max.

Comment: I have not used `jgraph` so far, but does it really generate text as strings in `.eps` files?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are trying to replace part of a string, rather than the whole string. Section 8 of the [psfrag package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) manual might help you. Otherwise, please make the `.eps` file available for download and add a link to your question.

Comment: @Ian: Your tip helped, I have now replaced the whole string in the eps file, instead of a substring and that solves the problem.

Comment: I have posted an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 8 of the [psfrag package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) manual,

> PSfrag can only replace entire strings, not just parts of one.

Hence, the problem is that you are trying to replace part of a string. Try replacing the whole string instead.