# psfrag equivalent for pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, psfrag

I am currently updating my workflow from the old `tex2ps2dvi` workflow (needs a lot of time and `matplotlib` and other stuff etc. hasn't a EPS output (only PDF, SVG, PS, PNG, etc...).

I am trying to adopt the font in my picture to the rest of my document. Normally I use:

```
\psfrag{old text in old font}[l][l]{new text in new font}
\psfrag{old text in old font}[90][l][l]{90 deg rot new text in new font}
```

But I always have to save it as pdf and then open it with Illustrator and modify it and save it as EPS then include it...

Is there a native implementation of `psfrag` in LaTeX, which can handle the text-replacement with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Related, or possibly a duplicate: [Why is there no `pdffrag` package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/5764)

Comment: mhh, simply not possible? well that's bad news! Are there any plans to implement it to pdf?? A kind of a pdffrag thing?

Comment: @user1536844 No, because as you say this is _not possible_: it's not a question of implementing 'something'.

Comment: I think more explicit than the other linked question is the discussion of psfrag in the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others/60797#60797

Comment: ok, thank you guys, you made the psfrag thing a lot clearer to understand. I think i will try this approach http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64483/16894. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean ``matplotlib`` when you said ``mytplotlib``?  If so, try using the ``usetex`` feature: I have had success generating figures matching my LaTeX fonts.  If this is the case, let me know: I could be persuaded to detail the process I use.

Comment: yes sorry i mean matplotlib... (spelling error). I think usetex only writes latex to the figures, but i would like to include only the figure itself the font (axis labels, ticks etc.) in my native latex document font (font size etc.) A more detailed explanation would be great... thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No `pdffrag` as you [learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/5764). I suggest the following "solution":

1. Create a minimal tex document which uses `psfrag` to insert the appropiate labels and fonts, and use it to include all your `eps` figures. Use also `preview` package which will produce a document with a single figure per page, and with a page size fitted to the figure size.
2. Compile that document with your habitual chain `latex`->`dvips`
3. Convert the resulting PostScript file to `pdf`. Let say that the result is the file `myfigures.pdf`
4. In your main document, include each figure at the appropriate point with `\includegraphics[page=n]{myfigures.pdf}`, being `n` 1, 2, 3... for each figure.

Alternatively, and I'm not joking, you may consider using TikZ to redo all your figures, specially if they are few and simple.

Comment: This is basically what the pst-pdf, auto-pst-pdf, and pstool packages all do internally `:)`. You're right; there is no other alternative.

Comment: The best solution is my answer below https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579145/164392
(using the overpic package) or psfrag with auto-pst-pdf and pstool described also in my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434761

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question and I'm not sure if this is an alternative in all the aspects, but it may be interesting to add the following:

I was able to do the replacement using the package `pstool` and the command `\psfragfig{}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{fileinepsformat}{%
 \psfrag{a}{$\alpha$}
 \psfrag{b}{$\beta$}}  
\end{document}
```

This compiles with `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`

See also:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [fragmaster](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/fragmaster) may help ? It is an automated Perl script doing the same. See the home page of the project for a detailed procedure of how to use the Perl script in order to automate the procedure explained in the starred answer of this post.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A full example would be of more use here, in my point of view. Just elaborate a little bit on your answer, please

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use psfrag with pdflatex,
I was resolved this problem in my answer for
another question with the same problem in
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434761

Also you can use OVERPIC like as :

```
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{Image}
\put(0,1){texte}
\put(10,20){$\alpha + \beta$}
\end{overpic}
\end{figure}
```

You can use grid option to put the tag in the right position, for example :

```
\begin{overpic}[ grid,width=0.5\textwidth]{Image}
```

And after you can remove the grid to show the pdf with all the tags
good look