# TikZ: How put gap in curve surrounding filled region

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following figure is a modification of an answer to [Sketching free-hand, importing into TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/sketching-free-hand-importing-into-tikz).

The labels $K$ and $U_y$ in the picture designate respectively: the blue-filled  region that has a thick solid boundary; and the upper-right-most region, with a dashed boundary, that is partly orange-filled but overlaps region *K*. Each of these labels is obscured by portions of the boundaries: label $K$ by the dashed lower part of the boundary of $U_y$; and label $U_y$ by the solid boundary of region *K*.

**Question:** How can I break those two boundaries so as to allow the labels to be more readily seen?

More specifically, is there some nice way to avoid lots of trial-and-error in locating suitable points along the boundaries at which to stop and restart the bounding curves?

(*Note:* The final picture will use shades of gray instead of colors red, blue, and orange, as specified by the now commented-out code block with the 3 `\definecolor` commands. I'm leaving the colors as shown so as to indicate more clearly which region is which.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}    
% Based upon answer by @marmot 2018/06/10
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/sketching-free-hand-importing-into-tikz

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%\definecolor{red}{gray}{0.15} % medium gray for region V
%\definecolor{blue}{gray}{0.2} % dark gray for region K
%\definecolor{orange}{gray}{0.6}% light shading for left & right sides    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[long dash/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.default = 3pt,  % size of the circle diameter 
x=0.44cm,y=0.44cm % scale units for overall correct size
] 

% Left-hand regions
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left,fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0.3,-2) (-1,-3) (-8,-1.2) (-8.8,-0.2) (-7,0.6) (-1,-0.6)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-8,-2.8) (-9,-2.5) (-8.5,-1) (-7,0) (-6,1.7) (-5,1.7) (-4,-0) (-5.5,-2)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-7.2,-1) (-7.8,1) (-6.7,2) (-5.5,1) (-5,0) (-5.4,-1) (-6,-1.2)};
\path [%draw,blue,ultra thick,
    name path=left arc,
    intersection segments={
        of=left top and left,
        sequence={A1--B1}
    }];
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    fill=red!30,
    name path=left blob,
    intersection segments={
        of=left bottom and left arc,
        sequence={A1--B0}
    }];
% Right-hand regions
\path[fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
\path[fill=blue!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
(6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
\draw[thick,name path=right] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
    (6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-left of point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=middle] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0,-3.4) (-1,-2) (-1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.4) (-1,1.6) (0,1.9) (2.1,1) (3,-1) (2.5,-3) (1,-3.7)};
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-rightof point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(1,-3) (0.6,-2) (1.2,0) (3,0.8) (6,0.8) (8.5,1) (10,0) (9,-3) (7,-3.7) (5,-3.6) (2,-3.6)};
\path[name path=circle] (5.2,1.5) arc(-30:190:4mm);
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    name path=aux1,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and right,
        sequence={B1}
    }];
\path [draw,ultra thick,
    name path=aux2,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and aux1,
        sequence={B0}
    }];

% Distinguished points & their labels
\node[dot] at (-6.5,-0.425) {};
\node at (-6.95,-0.675) {$x$};
\node[dot] at (3.3,1.5) {};
\node at (2.85,1.25) {$y$}; 

% Region labels
\node at (-5.625,-0.025) {$V$};
\node at (-2.5,-1.5){$V_y$};  
\node[] at (3.7,0){$K$}; 
\node[] at (4.8,1.6) {$U_y$};

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Region - need to break two boundaries to let labels be better seen.]

Comment: Well, in the linked answer there is a way: redraw the relevant pieces of the paths with the color of the fill. Another way is to use `dash pattern` to leave a gap.

Comment: I think the easiest approach is simply to position the labels so that they don't intersect the paths. That avoids the ambiguity inherent otherwise — is `K` the label of the region, or the label of the path?

Comment: Also, to actually provide assistance rather than just critique, you could change `\node[] at (3.7,0){$K$};` to `\node[] at (3.7,0)[fill=blue!30]{$K$};` for example. Doing the same for `U_y` is a little harder.

Comment: Indeed, I could move the label `$K$` off that solid boundary without ambiguity as to the meaning. However, moving label `$U_y$` off the dashed boundary will create ambiguity, since it refers to a region larger than the right-hand (now) orange-shaded region and is supposed to indicate that the labeled region includes the part of that orange region that "dips below" the blue-shaded region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Something that works for all paths, regardless of whether or not they are dashed: use the [`reverse clip` method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799). Draw the text node first, and then reverse clip a small region around it and then draw all the contours that you want to have a gap afterwards.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}    
% Based upon answer by @marmot 2018/06/10
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/sketching-free-hand-importing-into-tikz

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,backgrounds,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}
}}


%\definecolor{red}{gray}{0.15} % medium gray for region V
%\definecolor{blue}{gray}{0.2} % dark gray for region K
%\definecolor{orange}{gray}{0.6}% light shading for left & right sides    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[long dash/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.default = 3pt,  % size of the circle diameter 
x=0.44cm,y=0.44cm % scale units for overall correct size
] 

% Left-hand regions
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left,fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0.3,-2) (-1,-3) (-8,-1.2) (-8.8,-0.2) (-7,0.6) (-1,-0.6)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-8,-2.8) (-9,-2.5) (-8.5,-1) (-7,0) (-6,1.7) (-5,1.7) (-4,-0) (-5.5,-2)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-7.2,-1) (-7.8,1) (-6.7,2) (-5.5,1) (-5,0) (-5.4,-1) (-6,-1.2)};
\path [%draw,blue,ultra thick,
    name path=left arc,
    intersection segments={
        of=left top and left,
        sequence={A1--B1}
    }];
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    fill=red!30,
    name path=left blob,
    intersection segments={
        of=left bottom and left arc,
        sequence={A1--B0}
    }];
% Right-hand regions
\path[fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
\path[fill=blue!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
(6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
\begin{scope}
\node[] at (3.7,0)[fill=blue!30]{$K$};
\clip[overlay] (3.7,0) circle (8pt) [reverseclip];
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
% \end{scope}
% \begin{scope} 
\node at (4.8,1.6) {$U_y$};
\clip[overlay] (4.8,1.6) circle (10pt) [reverseclip];
\draw[thick,name path=right] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
    (6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
\end{scope} 
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-left of point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=middle] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0,-3.4) (-1,-2) (-1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.4) (-1,1.6) (0,1.9) (2.1,1) (3,-1) (2.5,-3) (1,-3.7)};
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-rightof point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(1,-3) (0.6,-2) (1.2,0) (3,0.8) (6,0.8) (8.5,1) (10,0) (9,-3) (7,-3.7) (5,-3.6) (2,-3.6)};
\path[name path=circle] (5.2,1.5) arc(-30:190:4mm);
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    name path=aux1,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and right,
        sequence={B1}
    }];
\path [draw,ultra thick,
    name path=aux2,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and aux1,
        sequence={B0}
    }];

% Distinguished points & their labels
\node[dot] at (-6.5,-0.425) {};
\node at (-6.95,-0.675) {$x$};
\node[dot] at (3.3,1.5) {};
\node at (2.85,1.25) {$y$}; 

% Region labels
\node at (-5.625,-0.025) {$V$};
\node at (-2.5,-1.5){$V_y$};  
% Derek's comment

%

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER**: Here is a simpleminded method that works for the solid boundary. Tune the lengths of a dash pattern such that there is a gap at the right place. Of course, you can make that more elegant by placing the text with `decorations.markings` such that it is right in the middle of the gap. Yet for the dashed lines I recommend the method of my previous answer. (<s>If you don't like that method, there is no need to load pgfplots nor its library `fillbetween`.</s>) **EDIT**: I was wrong, you do need the `fillbetween` stuff for the region containing `x`. I also implemented [Derek's nice comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446346/tikz-how-put-gap-in-curve-surrounding-filled-region#comment1120997_446346) but will be happy to remove it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}    
% Based upon answer by @marmot 2018/06/10
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/sketching-free-hand-importing-into-tikz

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,backgrounds,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%\definecolor{red}{gray}{0.15} % medium gray for region V
%\definecolor{blue}{gray}{0.2} % dark gray for region K
%\definecolor{orange}{gray}{0.6}% light shading for left & right sides    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[long dash/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.default = 3pt,  % size of the circle diameter 
x=0.44cm,y=0.44cm % scale units for overall correct size
] 

% Left-hand regions
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left,fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0.3,-2) (-1,-3) (-8,-1.2) (-8.8,-0.2) (-7,0.6) (-1,-0.6)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-8,-2.8) (-9,-2.5) (-8.5,-1) (-7,0) (-6,1.7) (-5,1.7) (-4,-0) (-5.5,-2)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=left top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(-7.2,-1) (-7.8,1) (-6.7,2) (-5.5,1) (-5,0) (-5.4,-1) (-6,-1.2)};
\path [%draw,blue,ultra thick,
    name path=left arc,
    intersection segments={
        of=left top and left,
        sequence={A1--B1}
    }];
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    fill=red!30,
    name path=left blob,
    intersection segments={
        of=left bottom and left arc,
        sequence={A1--B0}
    }];
% Right-hand regions
\path[fill=orange!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
\path[fill=blue!30] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % region K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
(6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right top] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of U_{u}
    {(-1.3,2) (-0.7,3) (1,3.7) (5.2,3) (8,1.6) (8.4,1) (8,0.3) (6,0) (4,0) (2,0.3) (0,1)};
\draw[thick,name path=right,dash pattern=on 118pt off 16pt on 300pt,
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 126pt with
{\node{$U_y$};}}}] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates % boundary of K
    {(0,-2) (-0.3,-1.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.3,1) (-1,2) (0,2.8) (3,2) (7,1) (7.3,-1)
    (6,-2.3) (4,-2.3) (2,-2)};
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-left of point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=middle] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(0,-3.4) (-1,-2) (-1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.4) (-1,1.6) (0,1.9) (2.1,1) (3,-1) (2.5,-3) (1,-3.7)};
% boundary of unnamed region to lower-rightof point y:
\draw[thick,long dash,name path=right bottom] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates 
    {(1,-3) (0.6,-2) (1.2,0) (3,0.8) (6,0.8) (8.5,1) (10,0) (9,-3) (7,-3.7) (5,-3.6) (2,-3.6)};
\path[name path=circle] (5.2,1.5) arc(-30:190:4mm);
\path [%draw,red,ultra thick,
    name path=aux1,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and right,
        sequence={B1}
    }];
\path [draw,ultra thick,
    name path=aux2,
    intersection segments={
        of=circle and aux1,
        sequence={B0}
    }];

% Distinguished points & their labels
\node[dot] at (-6.5,-0.425) {};
\node at (-6.95,-0.675) {$x$};
\node[dot] at (3.3,1.5) {};
\node at (2.85,1.25) {$y$}; 

% Region labels
\node at (-5.625,-0.025) {$V$};
\node at (-2.5,-1.5){$V_y$};  
% Derek's comment
\node[] at (3.7,0)[fill=blue!30]{$K$};
%\node[] at (4.8,1.6) {$U_y$};

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Locating how to do such things in the Ti*k*Z manual is difficulty-to-impossible (at least for me at this beginning stage of using the package)!

Comment: @marmot Sorry, off-topic: How did you get the reference to my comment in your answer? I didn't know that was possible. Thanks for the nice mention, BTW.

Comment: @Derek You make a right-click on the date next to the comment and then select `copy link`. Similarly, you can share answers by right-clicking on `share` below an answer and copying the link. (It took me also some time to figure that out.) (And if you want I can remove that part and you can write your own answer.)

Comment: @marmot Great, thanks! Please don't worry about changing your answer.

Comment: @marmot: Even nicer.