# Drawing an arc to this image

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I used the result in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/tikz-shift-and-rotate-in-3d) to achieve a rotation of a cone about an 3D axis. I am unsure on how to implement the following to this image:

[image: Rotated cone.]

I would like the imaginary lines that run along the 'volume of the cone' to be dashed to promote a better sense of the 3D nature of the image. I also need to draw an arc between the central lines of both cones to label the rotation angle $\vartheta$. Also is there any advice to make it look more '3D-like'?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{filecontents}           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,positioning,angles,quotes}  


\newcommand{\savedx}{0}
\newcommand{\savedy}{0}
\newcommand{\savedz}{0}

\tikzset{
pics/tester/.style n args={3}{
code = {%   

\def\x{1}
\def\y{3.4}
\def\R{\x+0.009}
\def\yc{\y+0.08}
\def\e{0.6}


\shade[right color=white,left color=blue,opacity=#1]
(-\x,\y) -- (-\x,\yc) arc (180:360:{\R} and \e) -- (\x,\y) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=#2,#3]
(0,\yc) circle ({\R} and \e);
\draw[#3]
(-\x,\y) -- (0,0) -- (\x,\y);
\draw[#3]
(0,\yc) circle ({\R} and \e);

\draw[line width=1pt] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0);

}}}



\newcommand{\rotateRPY}[4][0/0/0]% point to be saved to \savedxyz, roll, pitch, yaw
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rollangle}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pitchangle}{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yawangle}{#4}

% to what vector is the x unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newxx}{cos(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}% a
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newxy}{sin(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}% d
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newxz}{-sin(\pitchangle)}% g
\path (\newxx,\newxy,\newxz);
\pgfgetlastxy{\nxx}{\nxy};

% to what vector is the y unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newyx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)-sin(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}% b
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newyy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)+ cos(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}% e
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newyz}{cos(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)}% h
\path (\newyx,\newyy,\newyz);
\pgfgetlastxy{\nyx}{\nyy};

% to what vector is the z unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newzx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)+ sin(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newzy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)-cos(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newzz}{cos(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
\path (\newzx,\newzy,\newzz);
\pgfgetlastxy{\nzx}{\nzy};

% transform the point given by #1
\foreach \x/\y/\z in {#1}
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\transformedx}{\x*\newxx+\y*\newyx+\z*\newzx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\transformedy}{\x*\newxy+\y*\newyy+\z*\newzy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\transformedz}{\x*\newxz+\y*\newyz+\z*\newzz}
    \xdef\savedx{\transformedx}
    \xdef\savedy{\transformedy}
    \xdef\savedz{\transformedz}     
}
}

\tikzset{RPY/.style={x={(\nxx,\nxy)},y={(\nyx,\nyy)},z={(\nzx,\nzy)}}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic {tester={0.08}{black!6!white}{densely dashed}};
\rotateRPY{0}{0}{91}
\begin{scope}[RPY]
\pic {tester={0.2}{blue!14!white}{}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I would like then like to overlay both of the cones with a similar one that is squashed in one direction, but stretched by an equivalent factor in the other direction. The above MWE has a few flaws in achieving this which shows for one of the cones:

[image: Second objective]

Namely, bases of the cones are not in the same plane. The red cone is stretched in one direction, but is not squeezed in the other direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to argue that such things are drawn much more conveniently with the `tikz-3dplot` package and the `3d` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shadings}
\makeatletter
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-165} % - because of difference between active and passive transformations...
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\draw (-5,-2.5) rectangle (1.5,5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
  % just in case you want to get an intuition for the coordinates/projections
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) coordinate (X) node[below]{$x$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (Z) node[left]{$z$};
  % origin
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  % top
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=4,dashed]
   \draw[thick,solid] (O) -- (0,0);
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=white] (\tdplotmainphi:1) 
   arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray!80] circle (1);
  \end{scope}
  % left
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
   \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0);
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi))}
   \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.3,upper right=white,lower  left=blue] 
   (\MyThetaMax:1) 
   arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
       \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray] circle (1);
      \end{scope}
      % arc
      \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1]
       \draw[-latex] (0,1) arc(90:180:1) node[midway,above left]{$\vartheta$};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage is that you can change the view angles at will.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shadings}
\makeatletter
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{120+20*sin(\X)}{\X} % - because of difference between active and passive transformations...
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-5,-2.5) rectangle (5,5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
  % just in case you want to get an intuition for the coordinates/projections
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) coordinate (X) node[below]{$x$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (Z) node[left]{$z$};
  % origin
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  % left
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ttest}{sign(cos(\tdplotmainphi+90))}
   \ifnum\ttest=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi))}
    \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.3,upper right=white,lower  left=blue] 
    (\MyThetaMax:1) 
    arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray!30] circle (1);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0);
   \else
    \draw[fill=gray!30] circle (1);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi))}
    \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.3,upper right=white,lower  left=blue] 
    (\MyThetaMax:1) 
    arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \fi  
  \end{scope}
  % top
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=4,dashed]
   \draw[thick,solid] (O) -- (0,0);1
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=white] (\tdplotmainphi:1) 
   arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray!80] circle (1);
  \end{scope}
  % arc
%   \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1]
%    \draw[-latex] (0,1) arc(90:180:1) node[midway,above left]{$\vartheta$};
%   \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the "squashed" shape: it took me some time to derive the (hopefully) correct formula for the visibility angle `\MyThetaMax`. Other than that it is almost trivial: draw ellipses in the respective planes and then repeat the above.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shadings}

\makeatletter
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-165} % - because of difference between active and passive transformations...
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\draw (-5,-2.5) rectangle (1.5,5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
  % just in case you want to get an intuition for the coordinates/projections
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) coordinate (X) node[below]{$x$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (Z) node[left]{$z$};
  % origin
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  % top
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=4,dashed]
   \draw[thick,solid] (O) -- (0,0);
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=white] (\tdplotmainphi:1) 
   arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray!80] circle (1);
   % squashed shape
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.1,left color=red,right color=white] 
   (\tdplotmainphi:2 and 1) 
   arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:2 and 1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.1,fill=gray!80] circle (2 and 1);
  \end{scope}
  % left
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
   \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0);
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi))}
   \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.3,upper right=white,lower  left=blue] 
   (\MyThetaMax:1) 
   arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray] circle (1);
   % squash again
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi)*2)}
   \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.1,upper right=white,
   lower  left=red] 
   (\MyThetaMax:1 and 2) 
   arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1 and 2) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.1,fill=gray] circle (1 and 2);
  \end{scope}
  % arc
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1]
    \draw[-latex] (0,1) arc(90:180:1) node[midway,above left]{$\vartheta$};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another attempt. I thought the above one would match your description.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shadings}

\makeatletter
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-165} % - because of difference between active and passive transformations...
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\draw (-5,-2.5) rectangle (1.5,5);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
  % just in case you want to get an intuition for the coordinates/projections
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) coordinate (X) node[below]{$x$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};
  %  \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (Z) node[left]{$z$};
  % origin
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  % top
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=4,dashed]
   \draw[thick,solid] (O) -- (0,0);
   % squashed shape
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyPhiMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmainphi)*sin(90+\tdplotmaintheta))}
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.1,left color=red,right color=white] 
   (\MyPhiMax:2 and 0.5) 
   arc(\MyPhiMax:\MyPhiMax+180:2 and 0.5) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.1,fill=gray!80] circle (2 and 0.5);
   % unsquashed
   \shadedraw[fill opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=white] (\tdplotmainphi:1) 
   arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray!80] circle (1);
  \end{scope}
  % left
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
   \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0);
   % squash again
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi)*4)}
   \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.1,upper right=white,
   lower  left=red] 
   (\MyThetaMax:0.5 and 2) 
   arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:0.5 and 2) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.1,fill=gray] circle (0.5 and 2);
   % unsquashed
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyThetaMax}{atan(tan(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(90+\tdplotmainphi))}
   \shadedraw[line join=bevel,fill opacity=0.3,upper right=white,lower  left=blue] 
   (\MyThetaMax:1) 
   arc(\MyThetaMax:\MyThetaMax+180:1) -- (O) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill opacity=0.3,fill=gray] circle (1);
  \end{scope}
  % arc
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1]
    \draw[-latex] (0,1) arc(90:180:1) node[midway,above left]{$\vartheta$};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We keep crossing paths ;) Great answer. How could I change the lines running along the volume of the cone to be dashed?

Comment: Also the animation example has the function `sign` that isn't recognised?

Comment: @Sid In the "top" scope I just added `dashed` to the scope options. Does adding `dashed` to the left scope give you want you want? (Probably I just do not understand.) And what do you mean by `sign` is not recognized? On my TeXLive installation the code gives me a multipage pdf without any problems which I convert using [convert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) to the animated gif.

Comment: I got the 'unknown function sign' on the console. On a related question, I wanted to overlay another cone over both the dashed and non-dashed cones, but which is stretched along one of the axes and red in colour. This was why I originally had the \tikzset approach. How could I do this?

Comment: @Sid Hmmh, may it be that you have a *really* old version of Ti*k*Z? If so, you may want to update it, `sign` works fine for me. Of course, you could just replace it  by `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ttest}{ifthenelse(cos(\tdplotmainphi+90>0,1,-1))}` (the cases 0 is not important here). And if you append a sketch of what you want to your question, I'll give it a shot, I just do not unambiguously understand your request.

Comment: Edit made to question. Hope it's clear.

Comment: @sid Done. Hope my analytic derivation of the visibility angle is correct. In principle, one can also work with intersections, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448009/121799), but this turns out to be a bit shaky since (i) sometimes the intersections do not get found (amazingly this depends on the way you draw things, plots are more robust than arcs, it seems) and (ii) the ordering of the segments depends on the view, so if you adjust the view, the code may no longer give you the desired result.

Comment: You see how the red cones are wider than the blue ones in one of the directions? In the orthogonal direction, I would like the red cone to be narrower (by the same factor) than the initial blue one. I'm not sure how to adapt it on your method.

Comment: @Sid I made another attempt... Deforming the circle to an ellipse, i.e. squashing, is the easy part, what is not so easy is to guess the range of the arc.

Comment: is that why the bases of the two cones aren't in the same plane? I tried having a play around with it too

Comment: @sid The bases of cones are in the same plane. But the slopes of the ellipses are obviously different from those of the circles, so the angles of the extremal points are different (depending of course on the view angle).

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.