TikZ vs. pgf syntax
In the following LaTeX source taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435766/13492, do I correctly understand the syntax that the \draw let ... on line 7 continues through to the semicolon terminating line 14?
In any  case, how can I get at the values of \x1, \x2, \y1, \y2 as well as \xin, \xmax, \ymin, \ymax so as to be able to use them in subsequent TikZ commands? For example, in something like this: \node at (\x1,\y1) {$z$);
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node  (tmp)  {\includegraphics{tmp.png}};
\draw (tmp.south west) grid (tmp.north east);
\draw let \p1=(tmp.south west), \p2=(tmp.north east) in
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{int(\x1/1cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{int(\x2/1cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{int(\y1/1cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{int(\y2/1cm)}
\typeout{\xmin,\xmax}}
\foreach \X in {\xmin,...,\xmax} {(\X,\y1) node[anchor=north] {\X}}
\foreach \Y in {\ymin,...,\ymax} {(\x1,\Y) node[anchor=east] {\Y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Please provide code other people can compile. Nobody but you has tmp.png.

Just to say that if you're doing this because you want to draw on an image and use the grid to find out where things should go, there is a much easier method. So if that's actually your goal, please say so.

PGF loops form local groups and PGF takes some pains to keep definitions local. So you need to explicitly save things you want to use later. (Even if you want to use something in the next iteration of the loop, you have to save it, though there is a special interface for this case.)
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\savedxmin{}
\newcommand\savedxmax{}
\newcommand\savedymin{}
\newcommand\savedymax{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node  (tmp)  {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \draw (tmp.south west) grid (tmp.north east);
  \draw let \p1=(tmp.south west), \p2=(tmp.north east) in
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{int(\x1/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{int(\x2/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{int(\y1/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{int(\y2/1cm)}
    \typeout{\xmin,\xmax}
    \global\let\savedxmin\xmin
    \global\let\savedxmax\xmax
    \global\let\savedymin\ymin
    \global\let\savedymax\ymax
  }
  \foreach \X in {\xmin,...,\xmax} {(\X,\y1) node[anchor=north] {\X}}
  \foreach \Y in {\ymin,...,\ymax} {(\x1,\Y) node[anchor=east] {\Y}};
  \typeout{\savedxmin,\savedxmax,\savedymin,\savedymax}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

If you are doing this because you want to annotate an image, however, there is a much easier method. So do say if that is your purpose. If, on the other hand, this is simply intellectual curiosity, save the values globally.
A word of warning: we often use pretty minimal names in PGF/TikZ code. That is we write
\foreach \i/\j/\angle in ...

and that's fine in most cases because the definitions are heavily localised. But if you say \global\let\i\somevalue, \i will be unconditionally set to \somevalue globally. So you do not want to use names here which might conflict with anything in TeX/LaTeX/other packages etc.
In doubt, put \newcommand\savedxmin{} in your preamble so you get an error if the name is already in use.

I want to make the values of \xmin, etc. available to use in subsequent \draw commands -- including a \draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates ....' \within the same tikzpicture, as well as to add points with labels, arrows, curves, etc. The only purpose of having the \includegraphics and the axes with ticks is as a guide to pick points to make such a smooth cycle in TikZ; the included graphics is going to be a figure I've  manually drawn in an actual drawing program (such as Adobe Illustrator), which I want to convert into TikZ code to more-or-less reproduce the figure.

@murray See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/. Two answers there and links to further code. (I've not tried the links.) You're not drawing on an image as an end, but this is still worth looking at as a means.
