# Change font to computer modern for includegraphics

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdf

Is it possible to change the font to computer modern for an included pdf in LaTeX?

I know its possible to save texified text with Inkscape, but i'm looking for a solution with just LaTeX.

"Example":

```
\forcepdffont{cmodern}
\includegraphics{img.pdf}
```

Comment: The font directives are had-coded (and compressed) into the `pdf` file. It [has been discussed before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475) that `pdflatex` is not capable of modifying the included graphics. If you had your graphics in `eps` then [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) is an option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: There are OTF versions of both Computer Modern and Latin Modern which can be used with any application on your computer. If you have a way of regenerating the included PDFs then you can use the right fonts at the source.

Comment: [Why is there no pdffrag package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475)

Answer (score 8):

As @tochez already commented: **No**, none of the TeX engines or devices drivers handling PDF can change the fonts in an included PDF. And **PDF is not designed for this**.

The best you could do is somehow patch the PDF with an external program (like `pdftk`/`qpdf` and `awk`); but this will not produce the results you want if the metrics of the fonts differ (as they most likely will).

It will be much easier for you to go back to the source of the included PDF and change the fonts there.