# An equivalent of psfrag and polyglossia together?

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, polyglossia, psfrag

I need to use psfrag, and Georgian language, for which the only available possibility to get correct hyphenation that I could find was polyglossia. However, seemingly psfrag does not work with xelatex which is needed for polyglossia.

Does anybody know any environment which would give good Georgian hyphenation without destroying psfrag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers here [Psfrag or comparable tagging method with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63258/psfrag-or-comparable-tagging-method-with-xetex) give alternatives to psfrag, but if you want to use psfrag you can always process a small document with just the image and psfrag replacements using latex/dvips and then include the resulting modified image into your main document. It is possible to automate that (see `auto-pst-pdf` or `pdfrack` packages. Also see [Why is there no pdffrag package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/why-is-there-no-pdffrag-package)

Comment: Yes I'm forced to use psfrag - I am translating a book which heavily uses it. And I could not cut out figures from the original pdf since there are chunks of textual explanations in them which need to be translated. Now I will do as you suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Georgian hyphenation works out of box in texlive2013.
You need to install support files manually in miktex, since hyph-utf8 in current
miktex is without georgian support files.

Ask author of georgian support package at  http://tex.tsu.ge .
p.s.
 babel+hyphenation works for xelatex and lualatex also

Comment: Thanks Shakro :D

I managed to make it work with xelatex anyway, my concern was with psfrag which does not combine with it, and yes I worked with miktex. I tried texlive but it has less satisfactory package add/remove/update mechanism imho...